# Display Big5 encoding from dBase on the web

Tags: php, encoding, odbc, dbase

I have a dBase III file, the Chinese words inside is encoded in Big5.
With the help of PHP ODBC, I can retreieve/ insert record to/ from the dBase file.

However, I couldn't diplay the chinese words (Big5) correctly.

When I use mb_detect_encodingfunction to detect those chinese words, it appears as "UTF-8". I guess the odbc dump the data in the form of "UTF-8" instead of it's original encoding (ASCII/ Big5).

I would like to ask, how can I display the words correctly? Thanks so much for your help. I have struggling for this problem for 2 days.

Comment: It will be useful to state what environment and what database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to ensure the source and the display are both in UTF-8, and also everything that touches the data is set in UTF-8.

Start from what you are most certain about:
Check the DB encoding. You can set a server wide encoding, a database encoding, a table encoding and a column encoding

Next, check the php that handles it
The .php source file itself should be in UTF-8, the header and contentype charset etc should all be set to UTF-8.

If you sent the data to somewhere else like a javascript or other php pages for processing, you need to check them all as well. Be careful of any external library, or stream reader/writer, which encoding cannot be controlled by you. The connection you make with the DB may also alter the encoding.

Once you are sure the output is in UTF-8 you need to make sure the browser is displaying in UTF-8. You need to tell the browser what encoding this webpage is in, the browser read that in the header definition.

Good luck!

Comment: Gapton, Very so much for your prompt reply. As we still running some DOS program, for the sake of comparability, I couldn't change the DB encoding and I looked up the manual, seems no such conversion setup is provided (meanwhile guarantee the DOS program still can get/retrieve ).  Even I tried to convert every single character in the string to binary form by using following code      

**$value = unpack('H*', $c);    $binary = base_convert($value[1], 16, 2);**  The binary form every single character is not the same as ASCII code.  All in all, thank you so much.

Comment: Are you running this on IIS with FastCGI and from command line? If you are, praying may help lol. Anyway if you are on Windows try setting the system locale to Big5 (Hong Kong for example), or something **NOT** Big5 to see if it makes any meaningful differences.

Comment: Also, if possible, try setting up a Ubuntu virtual machine to run your PHP code and see if it can render the text. I have a general feeling that Linux works with encoding much better than Windows. If you are familiar with Linix + PHP then you should be able to set it up in 10 minutes. If you are not, search for LAMPP and install it on your Ubuntu VM, LAMPP is a package that installs everything you need. You will finish setting it up in less than 15 minutes.